# Unable to add data connection between SQL Server 2019 and Visual Studio 2019 using Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, server-explorer

Server Explorer-Data Connections-Add new connection---testConnection(:Success)-Connect(:Shows this error)

On my other computer, this worked completely fine.

[image: The error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps

Copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer from the working machine Or Click Here to download [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050) File.

Paste in This Folder Located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE

Now your error should be fixed.